# auto select an option by matching div data attribute and option value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Please take a look at this auto slider ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/57/)). The select box is there to allow users to jump to a specific slide. When the slider is on auto-rotate mode, I want the select option to change based on the current slide. Do you think it's possible by getting the data attribute (e.g `title1` of the present slide and matching it with the option value `title1`? Right now the select box is fixed at default option.

```
<div id="searchslider">

     <div data-title="title1"class="eventslide softblue">
     <h3 class="whitetitle">Title1</h3>
     <div class="slidebackground">
     <p>text</p>
     </div>
     </div>

     <div data-title="title2" class="eventslide softblue">
     <h3 class="whitetitle">Title2</h3>
     <div class="slidebackground">
     <p>Text</p>
     </div></div>

  </div>

</div>

<button id="left">left</button>
<button id="right">right</button>

<select class="select_title">
 <option value="title1">Select</option>
 <option value="title1">Title_1</option>
 <option value="title2">Title_2</option>    
</select>
```

AutoRotate Function:

```
 function autoRotate(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
      $('#right').click();
  },10000); //Pause Time
     $('.select_title').prop('selectedIndex',0); 
 }

 autoRotate(); // start auto rotate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code `$('.select_title').prop('selectedIndex',C+1);` instead of `$('.select_title').prop('selectedIndex',0);`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var intv;
var autoRotate;

var sliderplace = $('#searchslider .eventslide');
var W = sliderplace.width();
var N = sliderplace.length;
var C = 0;

$('#searchslider').width( W*N );

$('#left, #right,#auto').click(function(){

  if(this.id=='right'){

    C++;
    C = C % N;     // reset to '0' if end reached

  }else{ // left was clicked

    C--;
    if(C===-1){   // IF C turns -1 scroll to last one (N-1)
      C = N-1; 
    }

  }
  $('.select_title').prop('selectedIndex',C+1); // this line added for auto select
  $('#searchslider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 500 );
});

 function autoRotate(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
      $('#right').click();
  },10000); //Pause Time
     $('.select_title').prop('selectedIndex',C+1);
}
autoRotate(); // start auto rotate

// pause hover

$('#event_rotator').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
   var mEnt = e.type=='mouseenter';
  if(mEnt){
     clearInterval(intv);
  }else{
     autoRotate();
  }
});
$('.select_title').change(function(){

    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var selIndex = $(this).prop("selectedIndex");
    if (selIndex == 0) return false;
    C = selIndex - 1;

     clearInterval(intv);
    if(optionSelected){
        autoRotate(); } 


   $('#searchslider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 500 ); 
});

});
```

Here http://jsfiddle.net/K3bWS/

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the offset of each frame to get the current frame. Then read out that title attribute and change the option value accordingly

```
$( "#searchslider" ).promise().done(function() {
   $('#searchslider').find('.eventslide').each(function(){
    var parentLeft = $('#searchslider').offset().left;        
    var offsetX = $(this).offset().left;
    if (offsetX == 22){
        var dataAttribute = $(this).attr('data-title');
        $('.select_title').val(dataAttribute);
        console.log(dataAttribute);
    }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/62/

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I suggest this select field to be generated after the page is loaded.
jQuery should count the titles and create a options for this select field.

Once this one is done - it's all simple.

JS

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var c=0;
    $(".eventslide").each(function(i,item)
                          {
                             $(".select_title").append('<option value="'+c+'">'+$(item).attr('data-title')+'</option>');   
                              c++;
                          });



var intv;
var autoRotate;

var sliderplace = $('#searchslider .eventslide');
var W = sliderplace.width();
var N = sliderplace.length;
var C = 0;

$('#searchslider').width( W*N );

$('#left, #right,#auto').click(function(){

  if(this.id=='right'){

    C++;
    C = C % N;     // reset to '0' if end reached

  }else{ // left was clicked

    C--;
    if(C===-1){   // IF C turns -1 scroll to last one (N-1)
      C = N-1; 
    }

  }

  $('#searchslider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 500 );
});

 function autoRotate(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
      $('#right').click();
  },10000); //Pause Time
     $('.select_title').prop('selectedIndex',0);
}
autoRotate(); // start auto rotate

// pause hover

$('#event_rotator').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
   var mEnt = e.type=='mouseenter';
  if(mEnt){
     clearInterval(intv);
  }else{
     autoRotate();
  }
});
$('.select_title').change(function(){

   var select_index=$(this).val();
   C=select_index;




   $('#searchslider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 500 ); 
});

});
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/61/